# mysql update field in table from other table with the link in a third table

Tags: mysql

Migrating products from one instance of prestashop to another, I've ran into an issue of changed id's for images (id_image) but luckily same product id's (id_product).

Now that I have migrated the majority of the data, only the field 'cover' in the table dstshop_image_shop is missing.

Basically I want the table dstshop_image_shop to contain

```
(100, 1, 0),
(150, 1, 1),
(180, 1, 1);
```

Tables and some sample data are as below:

```
-- Tables for Source Shop
CREATE TABLE srcshop_image (`id_image` int, `id_product` int, `position`int);
CREATE TABLE srcshop_image_shop (`id_image` int, `id_shop` int, `cover` int);

-- Tables for Destination Shop
CREATE TABLE dstshop_image (`id_image` int, `id_product` int, `position`int);
CREATE TABLE dstshop_image_shop (`id_image` int, `id_shop` int, `cover` int);

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO srcshop_image (`id_image`, `id_product`, `position`)
VALUES 
(1, 5, 1),
(2, 5, 2),
(3, 6, 1);

INSERT INTO srcshop_image_shop (`id_image`, `id_shop`, `cover`)
VALUES
(1, 1, 0),
(1, 2, 0),
(2, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 1, 1),
(3, 2, 1);

INSERT INTO dstshop_image (`id_image`, `id_product`, `position`)
VALUES
(100, 5, 1),
(150, 5, 2),
(180, 6, 1);

INSERT INTO dstshop_image_shop (`id_image`, `id_shop`, `cover`)
VALUES
(100, 1, -1),
(150, 1, -1),
(180, 1, -1);
```

I think that my sql skills (or lack of) has made me hit the wall with this one...

BR
Mads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you need to multiple `joins` in the `update` statement

```
update  dstshop_image_shop dis
join dstshop_image di
on dis.id_image = di.id_image
join srcshop_image si
on di.id_product = si.id_product
and di.position = si.position
join srcshop_image_shop sis
on sis.id_image = si.id_image
and dis.id_shop = sis.id_shop
set dis.cover = sis.cover
```

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right! I have leaned a lot the last hour - it turned out that I missed at least one JOIN while struggling with using a SELECT statement.

Comment: @Mads, glad it helped. do post your attempt of the SQL when you ask a question.